# Unusual json syntax in React-Redux-Firebase documentation. Is it valid?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-redux, react-redux-firebase

[The documentation to React-Redux-Firebase provides the following sample code.](http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/populate.html)

```
import { compose } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { firebaseConnect, populate } from 'react-redux-firebase'

const populates = [
  { child: 'owner', root: 'users' } // replace owner with user object
]

const enhance = compose(
  firebaseConnect([
    // passing populates parameter also creates all necessary child queries
    { path: 'todos', populates }
  ]),
  connect(({ firebase }) => ({
    // populate original from data within separate paths redux
    todos: populate(firebase, 'todos', populates),
    // firebase.ordered.todos or firebase.data.todos for unpopulated todos
  }))
)

export default enhance(SomeComponent)
```

I am particularly concerned about the line that reads:

```
{ path: 'todos', populates }
```

I have never seen this syntax before. Is this an error? Or is it valid syntax? If it's valid, please explain what it means and how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is new ES6 syntax. Basically if `populates` is `'abc'` (just as an example), then

```
{ path: 'todos', populates }
```

means

```
{ path: 'todos', populates: 'abc' }
```

However, `populates` can be any valid value that can be used inside an object for that matter.

So, in your particular case, it will translate to:

```
{
 path: 'todos',
 populates: [{
  child: 'owner',
  root: 'users'
 }]
}
```

Ref: https://ariya.io/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's a valid syntax in es6

`{ path: 'todos', populates }`

this basically, translates to,

```
{ 
   path: 'todos',
   populates:  [
     { child: 'owner', root: 'users' }
   ]
}
```

Note that, `populates` is a variable being used, and writing the variable name in object, considers the name as key and value as whatever, the variable holds.